# IE tries to download json response from EE and jQuery Form Plugin

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer, expressionengine

I am using a safecracker form in EE to upload an entry via the front-end and i am using jQuery Form Plugin.

The problem is IE tries to download the json response. I know this is an issue that has been brough up a fair bit and i have looked around for a solution that works, but none of them were using EE and jQuery Form Plugin.

Here is the ajax js:

```
$('#publishForm').ajaxForm({
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSubmit: function() { 
        // Photo input validation
        var photo = $('#publishForm input[type="file"]').val();
        if( photo == null || photo == '' ) {
            $('#publishForm #photo_error').show();            
            return false;
        }
    },
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.success) {
            console.log('You successfully added a new entry with entry_id ' + data.entry_id);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Failed with the following errors: ' + data.errors.join(', '));

        }
    }
});
```

I don't know if there is another paramter i need to put in to fix it or do some hacky fix.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Json response download in IE(7~10)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943439/json-response-download-in-ie710)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is you response header's content-type / mime-type you are responding?
Is it

`content-type: application/json`

It seems like an IE bug, that if you are using lettercase header settings like

`Content-Type: application/json`

An IE client downloads the response.

Example response header:

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Fri, 23 Nov 2012 19:08:26 GMT
    content-type: application/json
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Access-Control-Request-Method: POST, GET, OPTIONS
    Cache-Control: o-cache
    Expires: -1
    Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-PINGOTHER
    Connection: close
```

Comment: Thanks @johannesboyne, I don't know how the header work with EE sending an entry via AJAX works. I know headers in EE can sometime be a something to work around.
Should i look to add the header to the AJAX?

Comment: definitely yes! A simple look into the network panel in your developer tools in your browser (I prefer chrome for that) should give you a list of all your requests. Navigate to the specific ajax req. and take a look at the response header.

Look at my answer for an example response header