# Json response download in IE(7~10)

Tags: json, internet-explorer, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, http-headers

I am trying to upload a file and return a json response regarding properties(name, size etc) of the file. It works fine in all browsers except IE.

IE tries to download the JSON as a file !

I have IE10 and testing it on IE7 to 10 by changing browser mode and document mode from the debugger.

I am using asp.net mvc4, the file upload action have HttpPost attribute and i am returning json response using **return Json(myObject);**

And here are my http headers

**Request**

```
Key Value
Request POST /File/UploadFile/ HTTP/1.1
Accept  text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Referer http://localhost:63903/
Accept-Language en-NZ
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Content-Type    multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7dc1e71330526
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Host    localhost:63903
Content-Length  1377002
DNT 1
Connection  Keep-Alive
Cache-Control   no-cache
```

**Response**

```
Key Value
Response    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server  ASP.NET Development Server/11.0.0.0
Date    Tue, 18 Dec 2012 23:44:19 GMT
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version 4.0
Cache-Control   private
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length  154
Connection  Close
```

I tried a few suggestions but so far back to square one !

Comment: So... what is the problem ?

Comment: my bad... IE tries to download json as a file

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE prompts to open or save json result from server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114360/ie-prompts-to-open-or-save-json-result-from-server)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You will need to return the json as `text/html` since IE does not know what to do with `application/json` contents..

```
return Json(myObject, "text/html");
```

---

Not sure but it might work (*and it would be more correct if it does*) to use `text/x-json`

```
return Json(myObject, "text/x-json");
```

Comment: The correct/safest content-type is actually "text/plain".  If you use text/html and return HTML as a value of one of your JSON properties, IE8 and earlier tend to do odd things to the response content.

Comment: When using "text/html" as the Content Type and using the `UpdateTargetId` property of `AjaxOptions`, if you return Content Type of "text/html", it will replace the UpdateTargetId's content with the Json you return. If the Content Type is "application/json", it works as expected. Is there any way around this?

Comment: @RayNicholus i tried to change the content-type to "text/plain", and ie8 still tries to download it, set to "text/html" is fine.

Comment: Returning 'text/plain' works on all browsers for me. Just have jquery expect json on the other end.

Comment: Could you please also provide a reference (from Microsoft, if possible) to the statement " IE does not know what to do with application/json contents.."? thanks!

Comment: @Dr.GianluigiZaneZanettini I do not have a ref from microsoft, but if you search the internet you will see that it has caused a lot of troubles for a lot of developers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701992/ie-iframe-doesnt-handle-application-json-response-properly and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483771/how-can-i-convince-ie-to-simply-display-application-json-rather-than-offer-to-do#2492211 and also https://twittercommunity.com/t/json-p-requests-mime-type-to-be-changed-to-application-javascript-instead-of-application-json/7236/2

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli : this is definitely true (I'm experiencing the issue first-hand) but some official confirmation (if any exists) is important, expecially when developing for enterprise enviroments.

Comment: Are you sure this is a good solution? Changing the resoponse type to something it is not just because IE is broken. Is there realy no way to tell IE just to show json as text?

Answer (score 3):

Even though this question is a few months old, I thought I'll add one more suggestion, just in case anyone else is using `ASP.NET MVC 3 or 4` and runs into this problem.

In my experience, when IE attempts to download the Json response as a file all you have to do to correct the problem is to add a reference to `jquery.unobtrusive` to your view.

for example:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
```

Once this is in place IE will no longer try to download the json response from a JsonResult controller action. No need to change the response type etc..

Comment: I have included this file into my html page, but IE still tries to download the json response. Any help? I have webApi 2.0