# Setting content-type to text/html to get IE to not ask to download json results

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I was wondering why in my asp.net mvc 3 application does the json response ask to be opened or saved in IE 9.  I came across some posts like this one that says to set the content-type to text/html or text/plain.
[Json response download in IE(7~10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943439/json-response-download-in-ie710)

Since this needs to work in other browsers like FF, chrome, safari, etc, I was wondering what this actually does and if it will break in the other browsers in the future?  Right now it seems to work when on the server I do:

```
return Json(results, "text/plain", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

But I wanted to double check that this a good cross browser solution.  I couldn't really find anything on the explanation on why this works, just that it works.  Can someone expand on why this is a good or not good solution.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it "text,/plain" ? or "text/plain" ? good one though.

Comment: @codebrain fixed, "text/plain"